# Subdomain redirect to the sub directory with folder name .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, dns, url-rewriting, subdomain

Is it possible to use .htaccess to rewrite a sub domain to a directory like that?

Example:

**http://sub.example.com/**

**http://sub.example.com/mycategory**

shows the content of

**http://example.com/subdomains/index.php?user=sub**

**http://example.com/subdomains/category.php?user=sub**

I am using this for first example but not working with category example,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub.domain.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdomains/index.php?user=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

this is not working,

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/mycategory$ /subdomains/category.php?user=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: `^(.*)/mycategory$` won't match anything, because with the request URL `http://sub.example.com/mycategory`, the path is just `/mycategory`. (And the leading slash has already been stripped off at this point, when you configure rewriting in .htaccess.)

Comment: The directive which you say is working for the first example would imply you are matching `http://sub.example.com/<something>`, not just `http://sub.example.com/` as in your example? But where does the `sub` come from in the query string `index.php?user=sub`? The "working" directive implies this should be the requested URL-path, as if you are requesting `http://sub.example.com/sub` - but this is not stated in your example? So, the "working" directive is performing a different action to your example? I assume the subdomain and main domain are pointing to the same directory on the filesystem?

Comment: @CBroe You are right i have did this for first condition `RewriteRule ^()$ /subdomains/index.php?user=$1`, and this is for my second condition `RewriteRule ^mycategory$ /subdomains/category.php?user=$1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for First condition use,

```
RewriteRule ^()$ /subdomains/index.php?user=$1
```

and for Second condition use,

```
RewriteRule ^mycategory$ /subdomains/category.php?user=$1
```

Comment: Your first "rule" would be the same as `RewriteRule ^$ /subdomains/index.php?user=`, but do you need the `user` URL parameter at all in that case? (You should also include the `L` flag. And the `QSA` flag _if_ you need it.)

Comment: @MrWhite You're right, I have included that in my .htaccess file.